# Creating GSON Object

Tags: java, json, gson

How do I create a json Object using Google Gson?
The following code creates a json object which looks like `{"name":"john"}`

```
JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject();
jsonObject.addProperty("name", "john");
```

How do I create a jSon Object like this one?

```
{"publisher":{"name":"john"}}
```

Comment: Are you talking about [Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)?

Comment: Change the title then?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Figured it out how to do it correctly using Java Objects.

```
Creator creator = new Creator("John");
new Gson().toJson(creator);
```

Implementation of Creator java class.

```
public class Creator {

    protected HashMap<String, String> publisher = new HashMap<String, String>();

    public Creator(String name){
            publisher.put("name", name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just to add some flexibility, I would advise using the Map interface instead of directly using the HashMap implementation.

Answer (score 116):

```
JsonObject innerObject = new JsonObject();
innerObject.addProperty("name", "john");

JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject();
jsonObject.add("publisher", innerObject);
```

http://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson

---

Just an FYI: Gson is really made for converting Java objects to/from JSON. If this is the main way you're using Gson, I think you're missing the point.

Comment: Hmmh. Thanks; not sure if it's a minor bug in SO comment formatter... anyway, to get rid of trailing bracket, link is: http://cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2009/01/entry_131.html

Comment: oh Ok. I thought you can use Gson for everything. Thanks for the info.

Comment: @Raunak: sure, you _can_ use it for that - but like I said, you're missing the point. Start with Java objects.

Comment: I've seen too many one-off Java objects which are only wrappers used to create JSON for one method, via Jersey or Gson. And Gson is less ugly than json.org.