# How can I use gson to create a set of key value pairs?

Tags: java, gson

I currently have this code, how can I add to it so I can get a JsonObject from Gson to append it to an existing Json file?

```
private static void writeFile(File f, String w_username, String w_password) throws IOException{
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    JsonWriter writer = new JsonWriter(new FileWriter(f));
}
```

Comment: Are you asking for [Java FileWriter with append mode](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1225146)?

Comment: @Pshemo I'm looking for ways to create a json object and append it to an existing .json file using the Gson library.

Comment: @Pshemo Mainly actually just wanting to know how I can create a JsonObject with a Key-Value pair.

Comment: I am still not sure what you mean by "...get a JsonObject from Gson". To create JsonObject all you need is `new JsonObject();` Then you can add to it string key/value pairs via `object.addProperty("key", "value");` or something like `object.add("key", otherObject)` (depending on what you want to add). We already have question about it: [Creating GSON Object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4683856)

Comment: @Pshemo but object.add() only works with JsonElements on the "value" property

Comment: Please visit documentation of [JsonObject](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/JsonObject.html). You will find there other methods for other type of data. Notice that `addProperty` has many overloaded versions.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your question. You're more likely to get a response if you detail what steps you took to try to find a solution.  Please see the Stack Overflow Question Guide: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`JSON` structure does not allow just to `append` more data at the end of the file. In this case more suitable could be `CSV` format.

To solve your problem you need to read the whole file as `JsonObject`, add new "key-value" pair and save it back.

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.util.Objects;

public class GsonApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File store = Files.createTempFile("store", "json").toFile();

        // Add two users
        JsonFileAppender jsonFileAppender = new JsonFileAppender();
        jsonFileAppender.appendToObject(store, "jon", "ewemn!32");
        jsonFileAppender.appendToObject(store, "rick", "923djks");

        // Print whole file
        System.out.println(String.join("", Files.readAllLines(store.toPath())));
    }
}

class JsonFileAppender {
    private final Gson gson;

    public JsonFileAppender() {
        this.gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
    }

    public void appendToObject(File jsonFile, String username, String password) throws IOException {
        Objects.requireNonNull(jsonFile);
        Objects.requireNonNull(username);
        Objects.requireNonNull(password);
        if (jsonFile.isDirectory()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("File can not be a directory!");
        }

        JsonObject node = readOrCreateNew(jsonFile);
        node.addProperty(username, password);

        writeToFile(jsonFile, node);
    }

    private JsonObject readOrCreateNew(File jsonFile) throws IOException {
        if (jsonFile.exists() && jsonFile.length() > 0) {
            try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(jsonFile))) {
                return gson.fromJson(reader, JsonObject.class);
            }
        }

        return new JsonObject();
    }

    private void writeToFile(File jsonFile, JsonObject node) throws IOException {
        try (FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(jsonFile)) {
            gson.toJson(node, writer);
        }
    }
}
```

Above code prints:

```
{"jon":"ewemn!32","rick":"923djks"}
```

Comment: Similar problem with `Jackson`: [How to append to JSON with Java and Jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58888004/how-to-append-to-json-with-java-and-jackson)

Comment: Also why do you assign the name "node" to the JsonObject?

Comment: @Raphael, `JSON` payload can be represented by tree, and elements in a [tree](https://www.baeldung.com/java-binary-tree) can be named nodes. Also you can name it as `root` or `jsonNode`. In `Jackson` library an abstract class for different types of nodes is `JsonNode`.